# How to create git patch from two files?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-patch

I am a newbie to git and I was just wondering, if it's possible to create a git patch from two different file. There is no git repo, the scenario is that I have a file and I modified it, now I want to create a patch with the difference between these two files. Any pointers? Or should I just go ahead with creating a repo and then modifying the file and then commit the changes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the [`git diff` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), you can try with:

```
git diff --no-index --patch
```

With:

```
git diff --no-index [--options] [--] [<path>…]
```

> This form is to compare the given two paths on the filesystem.
> You can omit the `--no-index` option when running the command in a working tree controlled by Git and at least one of the paths points outside the working tree, or when running the command outside a working tree controlled by Git.

Since:

- `--patch` is the default option
- You can omit the `--no-index` when running the command outside a working tree controlled by Git

You should be able to use `git diff` outside a git repo without any issue.

Example:

```bash
git diff --no-index --patch --output=mypatch.diff file1 file2
```